# How to get the directory to open a file from another file in Python

Tags: python

Having this directory structure. `fileOpener.py` opens the `testfile.txt`. And `fileCallingFileOpener.py`, `fileCallingFileOpener2.py` and `fileCallingFileOpener3.py` call a method from `fileOpener.py` that opens `testfile.txt`. What would be the correct path written in `fileOpener.py` so that it always work? Even in other computers.

```
\parentDirectory
    \subfldr1
        -fileOpener.py
        -testfile.txt
    \subfldr2
        -fileCallingFileOpener.py
    \subfldr2
        -fileCallingFileOpener2.py
    -fileCallingFileOpener3.py
```

I am asking something like:

```
os.path.join("..", "subfldr1", "testfile.txt")
```

But make it generic so it doesn't depends from where you call it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to get the location of the `fileOpener` module using `__file__` and then make the path relative to that:

```py
# parentDirectory/subfldr1/fileOpener.py
from pathlib import Path


def read_file():
    file_path = Path(__file__).parent / "testfile.txt"

    with file_path.open("r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
        ...
```

An alternative is to just use an absolute path to a file created in a temp directory, if necessary, or configurable by the end user with, for example, an environment variable.